# R: Graphing a table plan

Tags: r, plot, graph, graphics

**General Goal**

I am placing guests around tables according to a set of rules. My goal, in this post, is to have a handy function to display the names of these guests around their respective tables on a `R` graphic.

**Input Data**

`guests` describes the position of each guest at each table. Note that the number of guests per table varies.

```
guests = list(
   table_1 = c("Jack", "Christelle", "Frank", "John S.", "Lucia"),
   table_2 = c("George", "Amanda", "Alice", "Laura", "John H."),
   table_3 = c("Jeanette", "Elizabeth", "Remi", "Fabian", "Urs", "Emma"),
   table_5 = c("Roger", "Marry", "Henrique", "Claire", "Julia"),
   table_6 = c("Alphonse", "Marie", "Dani", "Rachel")
)
```

`Table_positions` indicate where each table should be positioned on the graph. I assume here that each axis goes from 0 to 10, where the point `c(5,5)` is at the center of the graph.

```
Table_positions = data.frame(
  y_position=c(3,2,3,7,8,7),
  x_position=c(3,5,7,3,5,7)
)
```

**Details of the graphic**

I suggest that the tables are represented by circles centered at the position indicated by the data.frame `Table_positions`. The names of each guest should be written around these tables following the list `guests`.

Comment: Do you want to draw table by table or all tables in the same plot ?

Comment: I guess you have to play around with `plotrix::draw.circle`

Comment: @ChristopheD. All tables (and all names) on a single plot. It allows to have a representation of the room. It is a table plan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Placement of Tables :

```
require(plotrix)
plot(x = Table_positions$x_position
     ,y= Table_positions$y_position
     ,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10),pch=".")
draw.circle(Table_positions$x_position,
        radius=0.5,
        Table_positions$y_position)
```

[image]

## Guests Positioning :

```
for(i in 1:length(guests)){
  Table<-as.vector(unlist(guests[i]))
  posTable<-c(Table_positions$x_position[i],Table_positions$y_position[i])
  nbGuest<-length(Table)
  for(j in 1:nbGuest){
    text(x=posTable[1]+round(0.5*cos((2*j/nbGuest)*pi),2),
         y=posTable[2]+round(0.5*sin((2*j/nbGuest)*pi),2),
         labels=guests[[i]][[j]],
         cex=0.5)
  }
  
}
```

[image]

I added table4 with one pepole named "Bla".
You can specify the text size with `cex` option (here 0.5).